# Is there more than one way to unwrap in Blender?

Tags: uv

What are the different ways to unwrap besides marking seams on everything and unwrapping?

Comment: There are also a few modifiers that provide basic non destructive procedural texture projections, useful for certain situations. See my answer here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57420/confused-about-unwrap-vs-modifier-unwrap/57422#57422

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your object, enter edit mode and hit the <kbd>U</kbd> key to access the options.

This brings up a list of UV mapping methods - I assume the complete list  (as identified by @sybren though ***Project from View*** appears to have two flavours). Complete list excluding the whole seam marking thing that is.

[image]

***Unwrap*** and ***Project From View*** seem to be the standard 'go-to' in response to a lot of UV questions - though this may not be fact as I've not conducted a scientific assessment of answers.

Comment: *Smart UV Project* is one of my personal favs...I use it way more than *Project from View*.

Comment: Yes, that's the other. I suspect those three: **Unwrap**, **Project from View** and **Smart UV Project**, cover most mapping needs so I'm concentrating on developing a really good understanding of them first.

Comment: I would b making my own textures from scratch for a video game. I would make textures on gimpshop. And previosuly in 3rd max i would unwrap each part of my model individually cuz I can shape the unwrap properly in the squat n make sure it is not stretched.. buy if i wohld mark all the seems on a model i.e prop from a street somethinhg complex, it would turn out funky so i unwrap individually.but we r switching to blender all the vids show marking on the seems in blender and hitting unwrap. Idk if that will have the same affect and make it all messed up like it did in 3ds max

Comment: Also when i unwrap one object its fine. Then unwrap the second object of the same model,the previous unwrap went away. And just shows the unwrap I just did. What happened

Comment: I can advise on your second comment @deidara though I'm by no means an expert in this area. The UV Editor only shows the UV map for the object that is currently selected and in edit mode. In other words, it only shows one UVMap at a time as a default. I don't know if it's possible to clone more UVMap windows to view more than one.  So if you deselect the second object and reselect the first (going into edit mode remember), the UVMap should reappear.  Could you also mark an answer as accepted if one has answered your question please?

Comment: So pushing the arrow is accepting it ? And ok I think ur comment before with the pic helped. And ur comment now helped. Now I'm wondering do UK the lil  orange dot on the uv editor ? Like could those b the other uv unwrap but minimized ?if it shows one uv map. How can u go back n forth to other maps -

Comment: I suggest asking these things as individual new questions as they are distinctly different to your original question asked here. Plus, I'm not able to help much more so you may get more help by doing so. (You can always link to this question in your new question).

Answer (score 2):

According to [the manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping.html#mapping-types):

Basic: Cube, Sphere, Cylinder, Project from View

Advanced: Unwrap, Smart UV Project, Lightmap Pack, Follow Active Quads