# Multiple stacked planes image distortion (Noisey Images effect)

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, compositing-nodes, displacement

The youtuber Noisey Images does this really cool effect where tiles that slightly distort still images as they and the camera moves through space.

Here's his newest video, he uses the effect with two photos at 1:03-1:10.

This is a still of the effect

[image: what the effect looks like when distorted]

Now i've got a couple of ideas of how to do the effect but not sure how to go about doing them:

One being applying a texture that produce large squares and apply it to the image. Then using a displace node to shift the large squares (multiple stacked planes) around. This is going off a tutorial I followed by PartnersInCrime youtuber: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7rHopldBPI

However this was done in Cycles and since I'm more comfortable with the Blender Render layout i'd preferably want to do it in that.

If that doesn't work then I was thinking of adding lots of planes in the 3D view with the image behind in the background. Then add a texture that magnifies the image behind it sort of like a magnifying glass.

Again, I don't if any of this is at all possible as i'm still pretty new to everything blender but I'm sure that with the help of you guys and gals out there i'll make something half decent!

Cheers for any help.

So far I've tried UV mapping the desired part of the image using a plane but it just highlights the whole of the image in the UV/Image editor:

[image]

I've yet to try the UV project modifier to see if it works but i'll append images if that doesn't work as well.

Comment: You may even be able to get away with doing this with the OpenGL viewport renderer alone, check out the [UV Warp modifier](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57420/confused-about-unwrap-vs-modifier-unwrap/57422#57422), it may help you achieve what you want

Comment: UV project modifier can help too... but yes, you should use planes moving between the base plane (corresponding to the background image) and the camera. These planes may use the UV project modifier or simply have an UV map corresponding to the wanted part of the image

Comment: From your last image in the question, simply scale and/or move the vertices in the UV map part. To do that: in the 3D view in edit mode, select all the vertices. Then in the UV editor, select the wanted vertices and use G to grab and S to scale (same principle as in the 3D view)

Answer (score 3):

A way to achieve a similar effect is the following:

- Use several planes or parts of planes
- One on background with the full image
- Others with marks or dust and an alpha transparency
- Others which cover only a part of the original image and moving between the background and the camera

low quality gif here...
[image: low quality gif here...]

The animation is the following. Planes are simply moving and/or scaling in face of the camera.

[image]

Two materials are used:

- A simple texture on one plane

[image]

- A texture with transparency for others

[image]

The plane UV are adapted to cut parts of the images where needed (you can adapt depending on what you want):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cheers for the detailed fast reply. One question though, how do you make those squares that dictate where the cuts are on the image (the 3 squares that move the man and dust)?

Comment: That's visible on the last image above. On the right add/make the figure you want (plane or other). Enter edit mode, hit U to unwrap, then in UV/Image view (one on the left), place the UV map where you need.

Comment: I've tried what you said but it doesn't seem to have worked. Instead of highlighting the area of the picture where I placed the plane, it's just highlighted the whole image in the UV image mapping window (on the left). I'll add what my set up looks like and maybe that'll illustrate better what i've mucked up. If i'm not clued up on UV Mapping to get what you mean then if you could link me a helpful tutorial or explanation then that might save us both a lot of time. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Using the compositor you can use a transform node to move the image and combine part of it over the original image, a mask can be used to define the part of the altered image that is visible.

If you animate the transform node values you can make the distorted section move, while animating the mask location allows you to move the position it is visible.

[image: BBB with offset section]

You can also use multiple input nodes, with a different offset for each so you see the same video just that sections are offset in time.

[image: BBB offset in time]