# Texturing GameObject with mutiple textures from an image

Tags: texturing, uv, image

I'm very new to Blender scripting, so please don't blame me. Especially if my first plan was to realize it in Unity and now I have to switch:

I've created a Blender model and now I want to texture it with data from an image. You can imagine it as follows: I've took a picture from an indoor environment in a floor and built this floor in Blender. The purpose is now to let the floor model look almost realistic to the taken picture. I also detected vetical lines (OpenCV) in the model and original picture in C++, thought it could be useful to compare both and map the textures, but I wasn't able to do this. I created bounding boxes (see image) between each vertical line in the original image to put out a dataset of textures, which should be mapped on the model. How can I do that by scripting?
[image: original image to blender (screenshot from unity)][image: bounding boxes which should be mapped]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The [UV Project Modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57420/confused-about-unwrap-vs-modifier-unwrap/57422#57422) might do what you want.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos could you please be a little bit more specific how I can realize it automatically for the diffrent parts on the wall?

Comment: Well to make it a one-step process all different parts of the wall would have to be a single mesh object, or at least share one single material with the same UV Layer name. If you plan on exporting it though, probably don't bother with the material part, just add the modifier to all relevant objects and apply it, or check if correct UVs are exported without applying