# Video Texture on a complex surface

Tags: texturing, video

If there is a noob forum I can post to in the future, please let me know, I am just learning Blender. 
I was hoping to play a video clip on a surface other than a flat plane (for example a sphere or the face of an extruded text.  Can you point me to an resource for doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: Check if these help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57420/confused-about-unwrap-vs-modifier-unwrap/57422#57422

Comment: what solution are you talking about: your 3D object will be a 3D tv screen? or it will receive the light of a projector?

Answer (score 2):

I was a noob last year, so don't worry about it.  We are all learning here.
Here is how I achieve a light projection effect in Cycles.  I use a spot light with the following settings.  Hope it helps.[image]