# How do I animate the scaling of a texture?

Tags: animation, texturing, node-editor

I have a B/W pattern on a torus and I wanted to make it slowly move down so it gets the effect of coming out of the hole in the middle.

I am working in UV mapping right now, and I'm scaling the raster up and down over my texture, which gives me the desired effect. How would I animate this?

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57420/confused-about-unwrap-vs-modifier-unwrap/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I do this is through creating multiple uv maps.

1. Create the first UV map as usual.
2. In the *Object Data* panel click the "+" to add a **new UV Map.**

[image]

3. In the *UV/Image Editor* the new UV Map will now be active. Move the UV Map (<kbd>G</kbd>) to the new desired location.

[image]

4. In the *Node Editor* create two **"UV Map" nodes** from the *input* submenu, selecting one of your UV Maps on each.
5. Plug them into a *color*, **Mix RGB** node.
6. Use this as the input for the *Vector* value on your image texture node.

   [image]
7. The **Factor** (Fac) value is now the value for going between the two UV maps.
8. Animate this value by pressing <kbd>i</kbd> while your mouse hovers over the *fac* field. You should place the first keyframe when the slider is at 0 and your time cursor is at the beginning of your animation, and the second when the slider is at 1 and your time cursor is at the end of the animation.

In the end, your final result should look like this:

[image]

*Please note: this method works for scaling, and translating. Small rotations (< 90 degrees) will work okay, but any larger will start to cause larger distortions and other methods should be use.*

I hope this was helpful.

Thank you,

Uncle Snail

Comment: Interesting technique, blending between two UV maps. It will work with scaling and translating but I don’t think it will work with rotation - the Mix will produce a *linear* blend between the two maps.

Comment: Thanks i like this technique! just before you posted i found a little add on called animall where you can just slide the UV map and it will make keypoints for you

Comment: @RichSedman You are most likely correct, in that rotation will not work correctly in regard to the speed and orientation of the rotation, however, I did try rotation during my tests and was surprised to find that it did actually work.

Comment: @UncleSnail Small rotations should be fine - any distortion shouldn't be noticeable. However, try rotating by 180 degrees.... you'll find it will collapse down to a point before re-expanding again - as each vertex will follow a straight-line path to the new point. Regardless of this though, nice solution for translation and scaling.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense and I didn't try a rotation that large. Thank you for all the input! :) (I will also edit the answer)

Comment: Maybe all you need is the "AnimAll" add-on by Daniel Salazar.