# Why are Texture Coordinate or UV map used before mapping node?

Tags: materials

I learned how to use textures. To control the size texture, I use the Map node. The input of the Map node should be a Texture Coordinate or UV map and it seems that they are very important because when I remove them, the texture disappears. I don't understand what they are and why they must be used. I tried to read the manual but it seems that I'm too beginner to understand it :D I'm not trying to do a specific thing. I'm just asking about the general concept. Thank you,

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57420/confused-about-unwrap-vs-modifier-unwrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping node only transforms texture coordinates(rotates, scales and moves) while UV Map or Texture Coordinate nodes provide the actual coordinates. It is possible to transform various kinds of vectors with the Mapping node.

Comment: I'm sorry for being stupid..what do you mean by the actual coordinates?  :) Do u mean that the UV map sets or controls the coordinates of the texture (or the image) in the 3D space so that it's wrapped on the object ?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. But also UV map is only one kind of possible coordinates, there are others.