# How to use simple textures and normal maps on imported FBX files?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, .fbx

I have seen several basic tutorials on how to add texture and normal maps to an object using the nodes editor. This works fine when adding them to Blender objects like the cube, plane, etc

But in my case I have some 3D objects in FBX files, where there is no texture included. If I import these files and add texture and normal map, nothing can be seen. Google wasn't able to help me, I guess my search words wasn't good enough to find a solution

In my example below, I have two objects. The weird black object is my object imported from an FBX file and then there's a cylinder. Both of them has the same settings in the nodes editor, but only one of them is actually showing the texture

I know there is something called UV that can be used for advanced textures (which is something I prefer not to learn right now if it can be avoided), but I just want to be able to add simple textures and then export it into Unity

Am I doing something wrong here, or is it not possible?

[image: Missing texture]

Comment: If you plan on exporting to game engines you have to unwrap

Comment: With unwrap you mean like what is used for UV editing?

Comment: Yes, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57420/confused-about-unwrap-vs-modifier-unwrap/57422#57422

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a bit. Now I have got something that works