# What is the difference between UV Unwrapping and UV Mapping?

Tags: uv

I am totally new to Blender.  It seems that UV *mapping* and UV *unwrapping* are the same.

Can anyone please clarify the difference.

Comment: Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, 
is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) 
and is [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing).

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57420/confused-about-unwrap-vs-modifier-unwrap

Comment: It's not the same. Although there are explanations for UVs and modifiers at the provided link, they are not explaining a difference between _Unwrapping_ and _Mapping_. Unwrapping, like the word says, is first of all like stripping the faces off as if you're peeling a fruit, you get the skin laid out in 2D in a big or smaller islands or whatever. Unwrapping usually creates a UV map automatically - however, this map is not carved in stone. While keeping the "skin's" parts, you can scale, rotate and move them in the _UV Editor_ to _map_ the UVs according to e.g. the textures they cover as needed.

Answer (score 3):

A UV map is the flat representation of the surface of a 3D model used to easily wrap textures. The process of creating a UV map is called UV unwrapping.

Comment: and the process of using a UV Map in a material is called UV mapping.