# How to project an image/video that moves across a 3D surface

Tags: image

For an animation video, I need to project an image, or a video that moves all the way across a horizontal 3D surface, see image. Ideally, like an optical projection it should not wrap around under the pleat.
Can anyone point me to a workflow/tutorials for this?
NB beginnerish but rapid learner[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57420/confused-about-unwrap-vs-modifier-unwrap

Comment: Or ... https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/57013/35559 ?