# Can textures be set to specific size and tiled that way?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

Not sure how to explain this, since English is not my native language, but Sketchup automatically tiles everything and you just have to set a length and width of the texture in the material section, you set it in inches, centimeters or whatever and it will be that size no matter what face you apply it to.

In Blender I can't seem to find that, I know that you can down and upscale textures in the uv editor and make them tile, but what if I want the same texture (to remain the same size, for example 5x5 centimeters) on 2 different size faces? I can try by downscalling it, but that's not precise, so can I adjust the texture size automatically and not in relation to the size of a face I'm working on?

For example I have a grass lawn on one part of the map in Blender and another one on the other part of the map, how do I make the texture to be the exact same size here and there, no matter what the size of those lawns are?

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56610/how-to-tile-textures-in-cycles

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos that all sounds a little complicated as I am a total beginner and I am not sure what I am supposed to look at, generated or object texture coordinates? Also, is there a way to not have to do this in nodes?

Comment: Object texture coordinate are more adequate here. Nodes are an essential part of Cycles, better start learning them now