# Applying a camouflage material to multiple objects without merging them

Tags: materials

[image]I have a turret model that I would like to apply a camouflage-like material I created in Blender. I can apply this material to individual objects, but that applies the material individually to them, taking their dimensions into account, and not to the turret as a whole (see included image where I demonstrate this by applying the camo material the main body object and then one of the body supporter objects). What I am looking to achieve is a seamless texture that spreads across the entire model - just like one would get if they spray painted a turret with camouflage colors in real life. One way to achieve this is to merge all the objects in the model into a single object, but that seems extreme to me. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56610/how-to-tile-textures-in-cycles/56613#56613

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link above, the answer refers to using 'Object' texture coordinates.  If you use Object coordinates on multiple objects, you'll still have the same issue you currently have:

[image]

However, the power of Object coordinates is that you can use any object, and you can use the same object for everything that uses the same material:

[image]

In this example I modeled a cube that I called "Texture_Cube" and I use that in the Object field of the "Texture Coordinate" node.  You can see all of the objects now have the same texture coordinates:

[image]

Here's the full node graph:

[image]

You don't have to use a giant cube like I did; you can use anything, even an Empty. You can also do fun stuff like rotate the object and it'll rotate your textures.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I needed. Worked like a charm.