# how to modify / customize a coloramp?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, vertex-colors, color-management

New to blender, coming from engineering discipline and want to learn more about rendering CFD/model results in Blender.

Right now I'm struggling with generating a coloramp for a 3d surface. What I've done is made a random 3d surface to test with, and developed a shading node setup to achieve a coloramp based on the geometry of each vertex. My current shading node setup and render looks like this:

[image: current render]

Right now it looks fine and what **I think** it's doing is scaling the min/max z-values of the geometry to cover the entire coloramp.

What I would like to do is clip the colorramp. For example, to have a min value of -5 and a max value of 5. Anything below -5 will be red, anything above 5 green, anything in between interpolated.

I want to achieve this so I can have a constant coloramp/values between frames if my z-values change.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: "*Right now it looks fine and what I think it's doing is scaling the min/max z-values of the geometry to cover the entire coloramp.*" That is what the *Generated Coordinates* do, for absolute positioning in local coordinates use *Object*, then adjust with *Math Node* operations. You can also use [Vector Mapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56610/how-to-tile-textures-in-cycles/56613#56613) to absolute Worldspace coordinates if you have scaled objects

Comment: Not sure I understand how this helps me. Are you saying I can clip the coloramp by using the local coordinates then math nodes to clip the values ? And how could I replace z values with another array of values?

Comment: More detail pertaining to the OP would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow your second (sub)question, but as far as the first question is concerned:

### Node setup

[image: node setup]

The important node I think is the **Map Range** node, which will take the Z-component of the geometry as input (set your desired clamp ranges here) and maps them to [0, 1], which the **ColorRamp** node requires.

### Result

[image: setup_result]

In this animation, I am changing *From Max* in the **Map Range** node. As you can see, all values above *From Max* get clipped to the upper limit of the **ColorRamp**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this absolutely helps and solved my issue..I thank you very much!!!

Comment: my second subquestion (sorry if unclear) is: say I have a mesh with n points..there will be n z-values associated with the points that I can use for a color ramp such as in your solution...now, say I have a list of n values that I want to use instead of the z values for the color ramp, how can I basically replace the geometry -> separate xyz nodes (which basically strips out the z values of the points) with a  list of predefined values, maybe they represent temperature, salinity, speed, etc...

Comment: @DerekEden I now understand your second goal clearly. My (perhaps bad) guess is that the most straightforward answer will require some python scripting; at the least, an approach quite different than my answer above. Thus, you may want to consider posting your second goal as a separate question. Edit: Also, my pleasure! These are neat questions!

Comment: thanks, expect a few more over the next couple days related in some manner to this one :) much appreciated

Comment: if you are able to help... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174943/how-to-use-external-values-as-input-for-color-ramp-shader-node

Answer (score 3):

Following @Duarte advice for absolute positioning, combining 'Object Info' and 'Texture Coordinates', I hope I got it right :)

Don't forget to 'Apply Scale' after scaling your object. Also, check out the 'Max Value' and 'Min Value' nodes feeding the 'Map Range' in order to clamp to the desired Z locations.

[image]
[image]

Comment: this looks promising as well, I will try this - between the two solutions I'll combine them where necessary

Comment: thank you!!!!!!