# how to use external values as input for color ramp shader node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, vertex-colors, color-management

All,

I've recently started dabbling in Blender to do some scientific visualization, like ParaView but 1000x prettier :)

At the moment I'm trying to tackle adding a color ramp to a 3D surface. As of now, I've been able to figure out how to use the surface's vertex geometry as the input for coloring. My current node setup looks something like this:

[image: current]

This separates the z-values from the geometry and uses them as input for the color map (after normalizing them in the map range node).

I want to do this exact same process, but instead of using the z-values, I want to use arbitrary values.

If I have a surface with n points, I will have an array with n values. These may represent temperature, salinity, velocity etc.

How could I go about doing this? Both GUI and python based solutions welcome! Would like to learn it first by GUI but will eventually be coded.

Comment: Hi! Seems like your question titles are pretty much the same for all of your latest questions. Please make them specific, thanks. Consider that this is not a regular forum, please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: there are several questions that are related but are distinct questions, I ask them individually otherwise I get penalized for putting too much in one... trying to do one thing with multiple steps...any idea how to do this?

Comment: I've ediited the titles to be more clear for my previous questions, made them a direct one question, and took out any subquestions at the bottom of each..this specific question was a subquestion to another question which didn't actually get answered..on the recommendation of the person who solved that question, I posted a specific question for this.. they may be related but they are all distinct questions...any help is appreciated

Comment: Your edit doesn't really help. Again, please take the time, read the link of my first comment and make your question useful for all of us by trying to find a specific title.

Comment: I don't understand? each question is a separate distinct question trying to solve one step of a multistep probelm? the titles are clear and unique?

Comment: `how to modify / customize a coloramp?`, `Why is my color map gradient (by node xyz value) working for x and y but not z?`, `how to use external values as input for color ramp shader node?` .. these are all different questions, with different answers and no overlap of the questions in each.. in fact I had overlap before and others who helped on those questions suggested I separate them out and ask individually.. I understand whee you're coming from but I don't know how I can ask these questions without asking multiple questions at once

Comment: Sorry for being a nitpicker, it is like it is here on stackexchange land. However, in most cases there is a good reason Derek...

Comment: I feel like I'm somewhat responsible for this. It did seem to me that @DerekEden had two  related, yet nevertheless distinct questions in a previous post. If reaching two goals requires two (potentially) distinct approaches, should there not be a separate question associated with each?

Comment: I wish there was this much traffic with people posting answers XD

Comment: @DerekEden I'm actually still working on trying to find an answer. I'm sure that it's easy to do - but I'm not a Blender wizard :( - hopefully something will come up soon

Comment: @DerekEden Also, your "Similar Question" link simply links to the photo in your question.

Comment: thanks, fixed that.. I don't know if I'm breaking rules now but I'm going to post my current approach, which almost achieves what I want, maybe it'll help you think or maybe you can help me solve the last step

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161664/using-float-property-layers-value-in-node-editor-similar-to-vertex-color  Can also use UV layer u, v data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop over every vertex after initializing different arrays for each of your vertex color layers. You can parse the init data from a file (eg .csv) with python but this is not covered in this answer.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]  # Get the currently selected object

vertex_colors = obj.data.vertex_colors
while vertex_colors:
    vertex_colors.remove(vertex_colors[0])  # Remove all vertex color layers form the mesh data

bm = bmesh.new()  # Create new bmesh object
bm.from_mesh(obj.data)  # Init the bmesh with the current mesh

verts_count = len(bm.verts)  # Get the number of vertices in the mesh 
# Not obligatory, I just use this to populate the vertex color layers)

# This dictionary will map each vertex color layer name to the data for each vertex
data_layers = {
    'Temperature':  # vertex color layer name 1
        [
        (1, 0, 0, 1),  # Color of vertex index 0
        (0, 1, 0, 1),  # Color of vertex index 1
        (0, 0, 1, 1),  # Color of vertex index 2
        (1, 1, 1, 1),  # Color of vertex index 3...
        ],    
    'Velocity':  # vertex color layer name 2
        [(i / verts_count, i / verts_count, i / verts_count, 1) for i in range(verts_count)],
    'Salinity':  # vertex color layer name 3
        [(i / verts_count, 1 - (i / verts_count), 0.5, 1) for i in range(verts_count)],        
    }

color_layers = {}
for layer_name in data_layers:
    # Create the vertex color layers and store them in a dictionary for easy access by name
    color_layers[layer_name] = bm.loops.layers.color.new(layer_name)

for layer_name, layer in color_layers.items():
    # Loop over each vertex color layer
    for v in bm.verts:
        # Loop over every vertex
        for loop in v.link_loops:
            # Loop over every loop of this vertex (the corners of the faces in which this vertex exists)  
            try:
                loop[layer] = data_layers[layer_name][v.index]
                # Get the value from the init dictionary
            except IndexError:
                loop[layer] = (1, 0, 1, 1)
                # Set a placeholder (magenta) value if the mapping array is not long enough

bm.to_mesh(obj.data)  # Give the data back to the actual mesh
```

Then to acces the vertex colors in your material, use the vertex color node :

[image]

Note that the "Temperature" layer was initialized with only 4 values, so only a few vertices in the right eye got colored and the rest of the vertices got mapped to a magenta color.

Also note that you can store 4 values in each of the 4 channels of your color. Example with the 'Velocity' vertex color layer used before :

[image]

Comment: looks insane...going to attempt this after dinner, will get back to you..thanks for input

Comment: seriously thank you, this worked like a charm.

Comment: @DerekEden I'm glad it helped you ! I have added a tip to add more information in each color's channel if you are intersted

Comment: @Gorgious This is a very nice answer. Do you know off-hand if the same can be done without using bmesh? I don't see any list like `link_loops` within an object's `data` property.

Comment: @JeremyHilgar Mesh has a `loops` attribute and then you can check the current loop's `vertex_index` attribute for mapping. But I'd rather use bmesh, any reason why you can't use this ? If it's an edit-mode problem, you can create a `from-edit-mesh`bmesh

Comment: @Gorgious No real reason why I can't use bmesh. I have been importing vertex/face data using `from_pydata` and it feels clunky to me to have to initialize a bmesh afterward. I guess I'm just trying to save time/lines of code - as well as learning to do things as many ways as possible. Thanks for your input!