# Is there a way of applying tile based textures to individual faces?

Tags: texturing, uv

Most of the textures I make for environments will be like tilesets. That is, 1 face = 1 "tile" of a texture.

Is there any quick way of applying tiles to faces?

Comment: Hello :). This sounds close to what *UV > Reset* does.

Comment: Perhaps related: [How to tile textures in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/56610/78972)