# How best use a texture image to a large/long object

Tags: uv-image-editor

Firstly from what I have seen Blender can only work with images which are square eg 512X512 or 1024 X 1024 etc. Is that correct?

I am creating objects for MSFS and my first project consists of large/long objects eg 9 metres long. It appears to me that if any texture image (all texture images I have found are taken close up to the object) is used then it either needs to be stretched to each face of the length of the object thus distorting the 'texture' on the object OR applied in (UV editing) so that multiple occurrences of the texture image are applied resulting in noticeable 'seams' between each image (unless the texture image is continuous ie the right side of the texture image matches the left side such as an image of a brick wall.
Is that correct? That there is no other method?
Just checking that my hunch is correct before completing my project.
I hope that I have described what I mean in a meaningful manner.

BTW now that I am feeling less intimidated by the Blender 'beast' I am gobsmacked by it.

Here is an example of what I mean by having multiple texture images with resulting visible seams.

[image]

Comment: While most people will tend to use square aspect ratios and powers of 2 for the resolution, it's not strictly necessary (although sometimes required somewhere else in a pipeline). You can work with whatever aspect ratio or resolution you want to; it won't break Blender or anything. 

Comment: As @HISEROD said, square ratio isn't necessary, this isn't the 90s :). You can crop the image texture in MS paint and use only a part of it.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56610/how-to-tile-textures-in-cycles/56613#56613 To avoid visible seams you will need a seamless texture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using an array of planks, you have another option.

1. Scale your UV map so it's only using a part of the texture (no worries, the rest won't be wasted)
2. Use the UV Offset in the Array modifier to avoid repeating between planks
3. Done.

Now you're using the whole texture and also avoid repeating.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jachym,  I have no problems adding an array.  I assume by scaling the UV map you mean press S then Y to change scale on the Y axis and press S then X to scale on the X axis. I have been trying that in many different ways and always either end up with the 'image' on my object (layout mode) stretched either along the x axis or y axis OR with multiple images with seams. When I think about it I cannot work out how a texture image of say a 1 metre piece of time can go onto a 3 metre long object without being stretched. What am I doing wrong? Please take this to chat (you instigate chat).

Comment: Hi :). Notice the UV map in my answer. It's not stretched, it's scaled proportionally to match the texture height. If the UV map doesn't have the same aspect ratio as the texture, parts of the texture simply won't be used. That's entirely ok :).

Comment: Thanks Jachym, can you send me the texture image file you are using so that I can attempt to reproduce what you are demonstrating and/or explain exactly what you are doing to scale proportionally as I only know of using S X and S Y to modify scale on those axis.

Comment: Thanks again I think I have it but I don't understand how I did it.

Comment: *"I think I have it but I don't understand how I did it"* story of my life :). The texture I used [is here on TextureHaven](https://texturehaven.com/tex/?c=wood&t=rough_wood)

Comment: Next morning. "The penny has dropped" "The wheel is turning and the hamster is still alive" (it isn't dead) . UV OFFSET says it all (gets each plank a different  part of the texture so they don't all look the same - great. Also using that texture helped me 'see' and understand. This thread is now closed.

Comment: @John Great job on learning Blender btw, i know it must be ridiculously overwhelming :).