# Real world texturing or mapping size/scale

Tags: texturing, transforms, procedural

Real world texturing or mapping size/scale in Blender v3.x without physically modelling the objects for architectural rendering?

For example, brick, timber board, roof tile, flooring etc.

If I wanted to create a real world brick wall 2m x 2m x 105mm deep based on a brick dimension of 215 x 105 x 65 and mortar joint of 10mm.

Using the Brick Texture node, how would you adjust this node to match this real world wall (2mx2m) size or match other various wall sizes?

So the brick count would be accurate enough to simply adjust the Mapping or Brick Texture scale. Or would I need to know how many actual bricks a 2m x 2m wall would need to be able to visually scale it within the Brick node?

I feel once you have the Mortar Size, brick width and brick height set and correct Blender units (m or mm) setup the brick nodes **Scale** would then scale accordingly. At the moment I'm just guessing the nodes scale number based on it being about 27 brick high and 8/9 bricks long.

[image: brick texture node]

The same with texture maps of an existing brick wall. For example using [Brick 5](https://www.sharetextures.com/textures/wall/brick-wall-5/) from [sharetextures.com](https://www.sharetextures.com) applied to the same 2m x 2m. When the texture is first applied to the default cube the scale is visually wrong.

[image: texture map wrong scale]

Would I need to measure the brick of the texture in Gimp (not sure how you would achieve this) to make sure it was accurate or is it related to the overall height x width of the actual texture?

If I manually adjust the Mapping node scale it will look right.

[image: texture map manually adjusted]

I've tried watching Bartek Skorupa demonstration of [Manipulate texture coordinates like a boss](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0) but I don't understand it enough to put it into practice.

I've also seen the [Magic UV world scale video](https://youtu.be/S876GhnIddU) and I'm not sure what is happening. My assumption is the size of an object is being measured and then copied to another object.

So with regards to both techniques how can I be more accurate in relation to a real world size/scale architectural renderings or am I just overcomplicating this. Thanks.

Comment: Please don’t add GIFs to questions for emotional reasons. It just clutters it up.

Comment: Hi :). Your UV map needs a specific texel density, so the real-world dimensions match.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56610/how-to-tile-textures-in-cycles

Comment: @JachymMichal, texel density! After a bit of searching and using TexTools texel density features, it makes more sense. The example I used with 2k texture on the default cube was set to 512 and not 2048. Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, thanks.