# Texturing a house

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm new to Blender and texturing my models. I was wondering when I'm texturing something big like a house, do I need to UV unwrap every object of the house and texture every object separately (if so then what is the fastest way), or is there a way to move the entire house to Substances Painter in a way to choose which objects I want to texture?

Comment: One quick way to unwrap several objects is to select them and then use one of the UV unwrap methods that don't require seams, such as *Smart UV Project*. The result is a texture atlas for the objects, that is, no overlapping UV islands. For the textures, you can create/paint your own texture images or use PBR materials with mask images. Here is an example that shows the second approach: https://youtu.be/1aNnERnHRZg

Comment: I see that the second approach is inside of blender, will the first approach work with substances painter? I think I prefer using different programs like zbrush for sculpting and substance for textures

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56610/how-to-tile-textures-in-cycles