# Adjusting mesh without destroying texture

Tags: modeling, texturing

I often find that after modelling and texturing, I need to make more adjustments to the model. This forces me to change the UV map, thus meaning my previous texturing becomes redundant.

What techniques could be used to reduce the amount of retexturing I do?

Comment: Avoid UV maps when possible https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56610/how-to-tile-textures-in-cycles/56613#56613

Comment: I have read your answer but i'm still struggling to understand exactly what you are meaning by 'avoid UV maps' @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: @Gunt.r it means (as a suggestion) to use materias instead of textures and map the material using nodes instead of UV unwrap.... Now, from me, my question to you is why do you need to "always make more adjustments"? is it because you don't like it? or a Client ask you to do the changes? or because UV distortion?

Comment: As Emir stated use parametric texture coordinates instead of unwrapping. What are you modelling? Why do you need to make changes? How are you adjusting textures? What type of textures are you using? I think this question is very vague and poorly formed.

Comment: @Emir yeah I just don't think the model is good enough.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I am thinking mainly in the context of a human model. I need to make the changes because I only realize the human isn't good enough after I've exported to substance painter. Sorry about the vagueness