Uvs and textures when building a level - How to keep textures even size when model size changes
I recently started building a level for a small game im planning, and during this building phase i encountered an issue i havent really thought about before. Its nothing major, but im interested in hearing how other people solve it to better my workflow going forward. The issue at hand is namely keeping the textures on your walls at an even scale.
To explain further; right now i have "wall segments" with even UV's that im building the level with, but in some places, those segments dont fit, they are either too long or not long enough. "So ill just stretch  this wall" i thought to myself when i was missing a bit of wall, but oh no, now the UV's are stetched. If the player is going to be running through that hallway i dont want the textures on the walls to have different resulutions or be stretched. My solution right now is just to take a bit of wall, cutting off the excess and filling in the holes, which seem to be working, but i'd be interested in hearing how people generally go about this.
Thanks!

Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56610/how-to-tile-textures-in-cycles/

The following shader is best for prototyping levels, but you should use the BBox operator from the MagicUV addon or customize the same shader in your engine before uploading it to the engine. 

Oh, thanks! ill try it out
